# TypeScript: convert tuple type to object

Tags: typescript, object, parameters, constructor, tuples

Summary: I have a tuple type like this:

```
[session: SessionAgent, streamID: string, isScreenShare: boolean, connectionID: string, videoProducerOptions: ProducerOptions | null, connection: AbstractConnectionAgent, appData: string]
```

and I want to convert it to an object type like this:

```
type StreamAgentParameters = {
  session: SessionAgent
  streamID: string
  isScreenShare: boolean
  connectionID: string
  videoProducerOptions: ProducerOptions | null
  connection: AbstractConnectionAgent
  appData: string
}
```

Is there a way to do that?

---

I want to create a [factory function](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-factory-functions-with-es6-4d224591a8b1) for tests for a class to simplify the setup.

```
export type Factory<Shape> = (state?: Partial<Shape>) => Shape
```

I want to avoid manually typing out the parameters for the class, so I looked for possibilities to get the parameters for the constructor. And what do you know, there is the [`ConstructorParameters`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#constructorparameterstype) helper type. Unfortunately, it returns a tuple instead of an object.

Therefore the following doesn't work because a tuple is NOT an object.

```
type MyClassParameters = ConstructorParameters<typeof MyClass>
// ↵ [session: SessionAgent, streamID: string, isScreenShare: boolean, connectionID: string, videoProducerOptions: ProducerOptions | null, connection: AbstractConnectionAgent, appData: string]

const createMyClassParameters: Factory<MyClassParameters> = ({
  session = new SessionAgent(randomRealisticSessionID()),
  streamID = randomRealisticStreamID(),
  isScreenShare = false,
  connectionID = randomRealisticConnectionID(),
  videoProducerOptions = createPopulatedProducerOptions(),
  connection = new ConnectionAgent(
    new MockWebSocketConnection(),
    'IP',
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  ),
  appData = 'test',
} = {}) => ({
  session,
  streamID,
  isScreenShare,
  connectionID,
  videoProducerOptions,
  connection,
  appData,
})
```

I tried creating a helper type that converts a tuple to an object, but my best attempt was this (and it didn't work).

```
type TupleToObject<T extends any[]> = {
  [key in T[0]]: Extract<T, [key, any]>[1]
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answers, there's no way to convert tuple [labels](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#labeled-tuple-elements) into string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types); the labels are just for documentation and don't affect the type system: the types `[foo: string]` and `[bar: string]` and `[string]` are all equivalent to each other.  So any method to turn `[foo: string]` into `{foo: string}` should also turn `[bar: string]` into `{foo: string}`.  So we need to give up on capturing tuple labels.

---

The real keys of a tuple are numeric strings like `"0"` and `1"`.  If you just want to turn a tuple into a similar type with just those numeric-like keys and not all the array properties and methods, you can do it like this:

```
type TupleToObject<T extends any[]> = Omit<T, keyof any[]>
```

This just uses [the `Omit<T, K>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) to ignore any tuple properties that exist in all arrays (like `length`, `push`, etc).  This is also more or less equivalent to

```
type TupleToObject<T extends any[]> = 
  { [K in keyof T as Exclude<K, keyof any[]>]: T[K] }
```

which uses [a mapped type with filtered out keys](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) explicitly.

Here's how it behaves on your tuple type:

```
type StreamAgentObjectWithNumericlikeKeys = TupleToObject<StreamAgentParameters>
/* type StreamAgentObjectWithNumericlikeKeys = {
    0: SessionAgent;
    1: string;
    2: boolean;
    3: string;
    4: ProducerOptions | null;
    5: AbstractConnectionAgent;
    6: string;
} */
```

You could also make a function to do the same thing to actual values:

```
const tupleToObject = <T extends any[]>(
  t: [...T]) => ({ ...t } as { [K in keyof T as Exclude<K, keyof any[]>]: T[K] });
const obj = tupleToObject(["a", 2, true]);
/* const obj: {
    0: string;
    1: number;
    2: boolean;
} */
console.log(obj) // {0: "a", 1: 2, 2: true};
```

---

If you are willing to hold onto an tuple of property *names* in addition to your tuple of types, you can write a function which maps the numeric tuple keys to the corresponding name:

```
type TupleToObjectWithPropNames<
  T extends any[],
  N extends Record<keyof TupleToObject<T>, PropertyKey>
  > =
  { [K in keyof TupleToObject<T> as N[K]]: T[K] };
   
type StreamAgentParameterNames = [
  "session", "streamID", "isScreenShare", "connectionID",
  "videoProducerOptions", "connection", "appData"
];

type StreamAgentObject =
  TupleToObjectWithPropNames<StreamAgentParameters, StreamAgentParameterNames>
/* 
type StreamAgentObject = {
  session: SessionAgent
  streamID: string
  isScreenShare: boolean
  connectionID: string
  videoProducerOptions: ProducerOptions | null
  connection: AbstractConnectionAgent
  appData: string
}
*/
```

And you can make a function to do the same to actual values:

```
const tupleToObjectWithPropNames = <T extends any[],
  N extends PropertyKey[] & Record<keyof TupleToObject<T>, PropertyKey>>(
    tuple: [...T], names: [...N]
  ) => Object.fromEntries(Array.from(tuple.entries()).map(([k, v]) => [(names as any)[k], v])) as
  { [K in keyof TupleToObject<T> as N[K]]: T[K] };

const objWithPropNames = tupleToObjectWithPropNames(["a", 2, true], ["str", "num", "boo"])
/* const objWithPropNames: {
    str: string;
    num: number;
    boo: boolean;
} */
console.log(objWithPropNames); // {str: "a", num: 2, boo: true}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8&ts=4.5.3#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-iDtqdvt8AIyGqvVvZQQnEm5UBvfADM9aLUAALDyGnyOX0UgwRWKJR2oABWBXTYrKyly9VZacANh7dig8acIWlRST-pQGBwKwLxFIFGo9BMQU4AAoIQUhAA6d8wdgASl43AfgnfV9sm3RhuiEUQJEMfwlFAqA1A0LQdH0KDjECMxLGsYRbDsL9TgPbJUBwAtgGPQMzwIB9WAAIkYKiDB2AxijgCBv1OJxE3wqBCOwKx+F7UtIQOdJpzrUVXUwKppybFsSXbBxt13BwD1bV9EFQdIH24n8XAEASaLoqBRIYqAmyYiATlNM5wGgeAkBPdNgAdYBsVZMAnVuBJCAhEhyEoWgGDQ9gySdK8-NvAAlfBUHCGhCD8YxbIDU9bW8TgDFcqpQG9EA42+bgeAhQQRHESR4sURL7PI1LlCgJ0bAwmAbHsU5TWTUMbitLJIw8iJ3JeX1Pm+KjfmBFIDOGy04XGlE0QxLFcQxcbpVlLkprJKjGWZXl2VaUcuiW5cuXGrUdT1WjjRatrU2tKreG80jkpWJyXIaNyPLoENrq6p4epjAx2vDbZupeXr3rjdioDNayUzDTr8gcgs+O+Eb-ioMtRrSbYIRmDqaUE0oIRm9FMSoHE8QJIlZIhZa1SoPGZgJ75NogFkhx2gUx0HNl+T28cxIlanDvlSYF1mAgVRWissghE7dX1Q15IcRSlLHbISLssiUue1y+oSC8fOvfy7w4YLQpvBgMvCLLZA4KAADIoEiikYrioxyoehziDSqBLetnLH17dXkCsVhAM-AwqHeqwwxoFJEBAN93ydE1vh-HhuAc195AadwVHyEoEgfVJwlmEAs5zh8g4gV8sgLugHy-L9X3cLUH0oqQDHpb9fyEB9I-6mrAi-VgpCCqAu8b5RCvAkqUPdjXHoIL2arqrCGqaiyVa6AicG117dd9KvNaex0dfeyj9PoxjwmYsfqJmcaxXccaWyo78E3JVWuN30-96jwtqyCR7IAp+Vgn4SXCNOFsFNWzMFOApPcylkCqXUppH+zkz79VwlAHS-AZhWEvmJdwVhjLQKTDfcyIQgA)

Comment: Clever solution, as always!

Answer (score 5):

In order to convert any tuple to object, you can use this utility type:

```js
type Reducer<
  Arr extends Array<unknown>,
  Result extends Record<number, unknown> = {},
  Index extends number[] = []
  > =
  Arr extends []
  ? Result
  : Arr extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
  ? Reducer<[...Tail], Result & Record<Index['length'], Head>, [...Index, 1]>
  : Readonly<Result>;

// Record<0, "hi"> & Record<1, "hello"> & Record<2, "привіт">
type Result = Reducer<['hi', 'hello', 'привіт']>;
```

Since we are converting from the tuple you are able to use only elements indexes as a key.

In order to keep information about the key/index I have added extra `Index` generic type to type utility. Every iteration I'm adding `1` and compute new length of `index`I

You are not allowed to use [tuple labels](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#labeled-tuple-elements) as a key since:

> They’re purely there for documentation and tooling.

Comment: Is there a benefit to this solution over [this one](https://tsplay.dev/mZb9Dm): `type TupleToObject<T extends any[]> = Omit<T, keyof any[]>`?

Comment: @jcalz I do think that your solution is better.

Comment: So do you want me to post a separate answer or do you want to edit this one?

Comment: @jcalz please post as a separate answer

Comment: All right, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70398429/2887218).  It's another long rant as usual.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** It’s impossible to convert a tuple type into an object, since information about the key is missing from the tuple.

When you say you have a tuple type like `[session: SessionAgent, streamID: string]`, I guess you really mean `[SessionAgent, string]`.

You don’t get to keep the variable names along side the tuple, they’re discarded, and there’s no way to restore lost information.

A workaround, if it suits you, would be converting `MyClass` constructor signature from positional params to named params.

```
// from:
class MyClass {
  constructor(session: SessionAgent, streamID: string) {…}
}

// to:
class MyClass {
  constructor(opt: { session: SessionAgent, streamID: string }) {…}
}

// now you can infer:
type MyClassParameters = ConstructorParameters<typeof MyClass>[0]
// ↵ { session: SessionAgent, streamID: string }
```